# Is there a method for iterating over an array in the view for select dropdowns ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view

High level overview:

I currently have a drop down menu in my view with multiple options for users

```
<%= f.select :carrier, options_for_select([["Select One", ""], "T-mobile", "Sprint",       
"Virizon", "AT&T", "Tracphon", "U.S. Cellular", "Cricket"]), :class => 'genForm_dropBox' 
%>
```

I'd like to update this dynamically by creating an carriers table so that I can loop through all carriers and add them to the dropdown without having to edit code to add carriers.

I've got a method in my controller

```
def craft
        gateway_arry = Array.new
        @carriers = Carrier.all

        @carriers.each do |t|
            gateway_arry << t.gateway 
        end
    end
```

I'd like to iterate over this gateway_arry array in the view for select dropdowns. Is there a method for this in the view for select dropdowns ruby? If so what does it look like?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean that ?

```
f.select :carrier,
         options_for_select([["Select One", ""],
                             *Carrier.all.map(&:gateway)]),
         :class => 'genForm_dropBox'
```

Comment: any tips on how to find this stuff in documentation?

Comment: Still doesn't work. A bit more context. I'm using devise to create members. Upon signup i'd like a user to select an item from a database of times and have that item assoiciated with that member. so i can call item.members.new in the consol without the following assiciation error: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Carrier(#97584750) expected, got String(#83658370)

Answer (score 2):

There's also `collection_select`:

```
collection_select(:post, :id, Carrier.all, :id, :name)
```